# NSTableView selected row highlight

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView with two columns, one is NSButtonCell and the other is a NSTextFieldCell. The text in NSTextFieldCell cannot be edited but the user can select a part of the text and make it bold. The current implementation is to allow them to do a double click and select a part of the text.  The problem is, once the user is done bolding, the highlight color at selected row still persists.

The NSTableView usually has variable number of rows each time. I cannot do SelectRow as false as I need to be able to select the row. I also need to support 10.5.8 so I cannot set - NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle as None.

My application is a Cocoa application, which needs to run on 10.5.8, 10.6 and 10.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the selected row as false. NSTableView has a method deselectRow. After bolding is done, you can deselect the row.